# convert ipv6 to ipv4 in contiki

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, contiki, cooja

I am trying to convert an ipv6 address to an ipv4 address on a exp5438 mote, in Contiki OS, using the implemented function "ip64_addr_6to4" :

```
    int ip64_addr_6to4(const uip_ip6addr_t *ipv6addr, uip_ip4addr_t *ipv4addr)
```

it returns "0" which means it failed to convert the address. in order to try the solution which explained in https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/31607766/,
I added the line below to "contiki/platform/exp5438/contiki-conf.h" :

```
   #define UIP_FALLBACK_INTERFACE ip64_uip_fallback_interface
```

while compiling, I get this error :

> contiki-exp5438.a(tcpip.o): In function `tcpip_uipcall':
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/routing/../../..//core/net/ip/tcpip.c:793: undefined reference to ip64_uip_fallback_interface
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/routing/../../..//core/net/ip/tcpip.c:779: undefined reference to ip64_uip_fallback_interface

I can not find the relation between the error and the solution. any suggestion to solve the error or to do something that the function works properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How would you convert an IPv6 address to an IPv4 address? Both are network level protocols that are inherently incompatible. While there are 6 to 4 Gateways, there is no linear conversion between the two.

Comment: it is the function.you can also find in [https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ip/ip64-addr.c] :

      ` int ip64_addr_6to4(const uip_ip6addr_t *ipv6addr, uip_ip4addr_t *ipv4addr)
{     
  if(ip64_addr_is_ip64(ipv6addr)) {
    ipv4addr->u8[0] = ipv6addr->u8[12];
    ipv4addr->u8[1] = ipv6addr->u8[13];
    ipv4addr->u8[2] = ipv6addr->u8[14];
    ipv4addr->u8[3] = ipv6addr->u8[15];
    printf("ip64_addr_6to4: IPv6-encoded IPv4 address %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
    ipv4addr->u8[0], ipv4addr->u8[1],
    ipv4addr->u8[2], ipv4addr->u8[3]);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The Contiki implemented on the RPL routing protocol, that Rpl is IPv6 Routing Protocol for LLN. I think you should use another routing protocol and environment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).